# XSS with HTTP flag true

Tags: penetration-test, xss, http

Since HTTP only flag is used to mitigate Cross Site scripting, we cannot perform XSS on the web application?

If we can, What are some best real time examples to pentest XSS when HTTPOnly Flag is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since HTTP only flag is used to mitigate Cross Site scripting ...

[httponly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F) does not at all protect against the XSS itself.

All what it does is limit the impact a successful XSS can have by making sure that the cookies with such a flag can not be read by JavaScript. If a session cookie is protected with `httponly` an attacker cannot steal it using XSS and thus cannot reuse this session within another browser.

But an attacker can still do lots of harm without stealing the session cookie. It can for example read any information inside the current page (i.e. read the DOM), no matter if they are send by the server or if they were just entered by the user. This includes passwords entered by the user. And even though the attacker cannot read the session cookie itself he can let the users browser make new requests which include the session cookie and which are therefore authenticated.

Based on this knowledge you can refine your search for XSS examples. For example searching for [xss read password](https://www.google.com/search?q=xss+read+password) gives you [XSS, Passwords theft using JavaScript](http://www.martani.net/2009/08/xss-steal-passwords-using-javascript.html). Also [5 Practical Scenarios for XSS Attacks](https://pentest-tools.com/blog/xss-attacks-practical-scenarios/) shows in how to *Perform unauthorized activities* (attack #2) or *Capture the key strokes by injecting a keylogger* (attack #4), none of this requires access to the cookie and thus works with `httponly` set.

Comment: thank you for the example links, they are really helpful. one small question from  "5 Practical Scenarios for XSS Attacks shows in how to Perform unauthorized activities (attack #2)". 
How can we get access to inject payload or script  in victim url?

Comment: @EshwarP: *"How can we get access to inject payload or script in victim url?"* - asking how to put script into the victims URL is essentially asking how to do XSS. There is no generic way, details depend always on the specific vulnerability which allows XSS in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> Since HTTP only flag is used to mitigate Cross Site scripting, we
>   cannot perform XSS on the web application?

Yes,if a website is vulnerable to cross site scripting you can still inject javascript and execute javascript on the client.

> HTTP only flag is used to mitigate Cross Site scripting

The meaning of mitigate is "**make (something bad) less severe**".It doesn't solve XSS just makes it less severe.How?Well XSS is almost always used to steal session cookies.If an http only flag is set on a session cookie then the javascript on the client cannot read the session cookie and hence the attacker cannot steal it thereby making XSS less severe.